# Airprint frame on screen for badges

Tags: xcode, swiftui, airprint, printscreen

I found a couple items regarding AirPrint.  I want to print a frame in a view i have but am having some trouble.

```
    struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group{
                Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundStyle(.tint)
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            
        }
        .frame(width: 390, height: 300, alignment: .center)
        .border(Color.black)
        .cornerRadius(15.0)
        .padding()
        
        Button{
            print()
        } label:
        {
            Text("print")
        }
    }
   
    
    private func print(){
        // UIPrintInteractionController presents a user interface and manages the printing
        let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared

        // UIPrintInfo contains information about the print job
        let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfo.OutputType.general
        printInfo.jobName = "myPrintJob"
        printController.printInfo = printInfo
                
        // You can also format printing text, for example, the insets for the printing page
        let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: "TestDevLab blog 2018")
        
        formatter.perPageContentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 90, left: 90, bottom: 90, right: 90)
        printController.printFormatter = formatter
                    
        // Present print controller like usual view controller. Also completionHandler is available if needed.
        printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
}
```

the func "print" was pulled from an article i found and prints the text: "TestDevLab blog"

i also found an article to print a view as a image but am having trouble implementing it into the above.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( view.frame.size, false, 0)
view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
let viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

let information = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
information.outputType = UIPrintInfo.OutputType.general
information.jobName = "Print Badge"

let printerViewController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
printerViewController.printInfo = information
printerViewController.printingItem = viewImage
printerViewController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

The UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions ( view.frame.size, false, 0).  how do i set the view to my ContentView()?

anyone done anything like this before??

thanks.

ja